# Parsing many blocks with foldLine

Tags: parsing, haskell, indentation, megaparsec

For this simplified problem, I am trying to parse an input that looks like

```
foo bar
 baz quux 
 woo
hoo xyzzy 
  glulx
```

into

```
[["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux", "woo"], ["hoo", "xyzzy", "glulx"]]
```

The code I've tried is as follows:

```
import qualified Text.Megaparsec.Lexer as L
import Text.Megaparsec hiding (space)
import Text.Megaparsec.Char hiding (space)
import Text.Megaparsec.String
import Control.Monad (void)
import Control.Applicative

space :: Parser ()
space = L.space (void spaceChar) empty empty

item :: Parser () -> Parser String
item sp = L.lexeme sp $ some letterChar

items :: Parser () -> Parser [String]
items sp = L.lineFold sp $ \sp' -> some (item sp')

items_ :: Parser [String]
items_ = items space
```

This works for one block of `items`:

```
λ» parseTest items_ "foo bar\n baz quux\n woo"
["foo","bar","baz","quux","woo"]
```

But as soon as I try to parse `many items`, it fails on the first unindented line:

```
λ» parseTest (many items_) "foo bar\n baz quux\n woo\nhoo xyzzy\n  glulx"
4:1:
incorrect indentation (got 1, should be greater than 1)
```

or, with an even simpler input:

```
λ» parseTest (many items_) "a\nb"
2:1:
incorrect indentation (got 1, should be greater than 1)
```

Comment: @ron: `parsec` does not backtrack by default, you have to use `try`, otherwise already consumed characters/tokens are "gone". You're thinking of `attoparsec`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Megaparsec's author is here :-) One thing to remember when you work with
Megaparsec is that it's lexer module is really “low-level” on purpose. It
does not do anything you cannot build yourself, it doesn't lock you into any
particular “framework”. So basicly in your case you have space consumer
`sp'` provided for you, but you should use it carefully because it will sure
fail when you have indentation level less or equal to indentation level of
start of the whole fold, that's how your fold ends, by the way.

To quote [the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-5.0.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec-Lexer.html#v:lineFold):

> Create a parser that supports line-folding. The first argument is used to
>   consume white space between components of line fold, thus it must consume
>   newlines in order to work properly. The second argument is a callback that
>   receives custom space-consuming parser as argument. This parser should be
>   used after separate components of line fold that can be put on different
>   lines.

```hs
sc = L.space (void spaceChar) empty empty

myFold = L.lineFold sc $ \sc' -> do
  L.symbol sc' "foo"
  L.symbol sc' "bar"
  L.symbol sc  "baz" -- for the last symbol we use normal space consumer
```

Line fold cannot run indefinitely so you should expect it to fail with error
message similar to what you have right now. To succeed, you should think
about a way for it to finish. This is usually done via using of “normal”
space consumer at the end of line fold:

```hs
space :: Parser ()
space = L.space (void spaceChar) empty empty

item :: Parser String
item = some letterChar

items :: Parser () -> Parser [String]
items sp = L.lineFold sp $ \sp' ->
  item `sepBy1` try sp' <* sp

items_ :: Parser [String]
items_ = items space
```

`` item `sepBy1` try sp' `` runs till it fails and then `sp` grabs the rest, so
next fold can be parsed.

```hs
λ> parseTest items_ "foo bar\n baz quux\n woo"
["foo","bar","baz","quux","woo"]
λ> parseTest (many items_) "foo bar\n baz quux\n woo\nhoo xyzzy\n  glulx"
[["foo","bar","baz","quux","woo"],["hoo","xyzzy","glulx"]]
λ> parseTest (many items_) "foo bar\n baz quux\n woo\nhoo\nxyzzy\n  glulx"
[["foo","bar","baz","quux","woo"],["hoo"],["xyzzy","glulx"]]
```

Comment: In my real parser, `item` is much more complicated (and can contain further `foldLine` blocks) . How would I externalize the consumption of whitespace in that case?

Comment: To put it in more concrete terms, do you have examples of parsing e.g. Haskell 98 with Megaparsec?

Comment: @Cactus, I don't have examples that parse entire languages like Haskell98. I don't know if there are examples of that coded with Parsec which has been around for long time. `Text.Parsec.Token` certainly cannot parse Haskell. Megaparsec 5 is two days old, we have a tutorial about indentation-sensitive parsing on our site, and Haddocks but that's about it. Without seeing your code it's hard to advise but if your problem is solvable via use of monadic parser combinators, Megaparsec won't get in your way. You just need to find how to express it.

Comment: @Cactus, remember `Text.Megaparsec.Lexer` is just a collection of useful sortcuts that seem to make sense.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm marking this answer as accepted, then, and will post a more detailed example with nested `lineFold`s later.

Comment: Isn't `items sp` equivalent to ```L.lexeme sp $ L.lineFold $ \sp' -> item `sepBy1` try sp'```?

Comment: @Cactus, looks like it is. This is nice, isn't it?